# node-oracledb other language encoding

Tags: node.js

I'm newbie at node.js!

I'm in trouble at encoding 'Korean'.

My oracle database has Korean String data, and directly Console.log(Korean text) is worked.

but when I use execute function and select query, and Console.log(return rows), It isn't work. text is broken.

I set all encoding type in Eclipse as UTF-8. As I think, I have to set something controlling encoding type in oracledb module, But I can`t find how set it.

please help me. I have to resolve this problem at any cost!!!

I already set NLS_LANG.
I don't set it. I just check it and take picture. It is already done when I found registry.

Windows 7 64bit
node 0.10.38
Eclipse / NodeClipse

---

It's resloved.

I set my NLS_LANG variable, as 'original value'.UTF8 And It works.

This is from master of node-oracledb. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From version 1.0, node-oracledb always sets the "client" character encoding to Oracle's AL32UTF8 value. See https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md